# Not able to drag an application into new sda1 HD?

Tags: ext4

My primary HD (sdb) is a SDD (Solid State Drive). I installed and formatted a new 300 GB drive (sda) to ext4.

I am not able to drag an application.run file into the new sda1. Why? Because it need a file system?

I checked to see that it is already mounted.

Below is the result of `lsblk`

```
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0 298.1G  0 part /media/ste/787fbb8c-cad8-4e1f-abc6-6a3802c46047
└─sda2                      8:2    0     9M  0 part /media/ste/ea853a1d-3d86-4e66-92b7-aef405c68bec
sdb                         8:16   0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sdb1                      8:17   0   243M  0 part /boot 
├─sdb2                      8:18   0     1K  0 part 
└─sdb5                      8:21   0   119G  0 part 
├─ste--vg-root (dm-0)   252:0    0 115.1G  0 lvm  /
└─ste--vg-swap_1 (dm-1) 252:1    0   3.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

and `sudo blkid`

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="787fbb8c-cad8-4e1f-abc6-6a3802c46047" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="ea853a1d-3d86-4e66-92b7-aef405c68bec" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="44af5883-ca2a-4285-baef-1f86e7fc5055" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sdb5: UUID="plLxEL-v3Ac-MHUu-4gGo-rlox-KR0Q-WSbfxh" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/ste--vg-root: UUID="52630c34-4845-471b-8e3b-2b007c057b3b" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/ste--vg-swap_1: UUID="db3e1d1a-b535-46be-9569-6af343d8491c" TYPE="swap"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set a filesystem on the `sda1`? Setting the partition type via `fdisk` is only the first part of the setup. The next would be to create a file system. First step should be to make sure that device is not mounted by using `umount` like this:

```
sudo umount /media/ste/787fbb8c-cad8-4e1f-abc6-6a3802c46047
```

Next, create the actual filesystem on the partition. Please note that this will wipe all data on `sda1` so please be sure that you are absolutely positive there is no data there before running:

```
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sda1
```

After that is done, you should be able to remount the volume as before.